# Ramdisks in OpenSuse 13.1

Tags: opensuse, tmpfs, ramdisk

I've just installed OpenSuse 13.1, and noticed 5 **tmpfs** ramdisks in the partitioner, mapped to `/dev/shm`, `/run`, `/sys/fs/cgroup`, `/var/lock` and `/var/run`.

I don't remember seeing these ramdisks in the past when I've used OpenSuse, though I did recently upgrade to a new SSD. I was wondering if anybody knew what they were for or whether it was good to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/shm` is supposed to by used only by `shm_*` and `sem_*` functions implementing the POSIX [shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and [semaphores](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) features. It's been used for quite some time and given its role it makes sense to keep it in memory.

`/sys/fs/cgroup` is more like a virtual filesystem used for [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt), so again it makes sense to store it in memory, just like `/proc`.

The rest of the directories are part of the new `/run` directory [proposal](https://bugs.linuxfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718) made Lennart Poettering, the author of **systemd**:

> `/run` is now a **tmpfs**, and `/var/run` is bind mounted to it.
>   `/var/lock` is bind mounted to `/run/lock`.

OpenSuse uses systemd, so you can't get rid of these as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the intention is to be sure that those directories are empty after reboot. These ramdisks consume only a tiny amount of RAM.

If you disable them then you have to care yourself that these directories are empty. Maybe it is not easy to get this action into that part of the boot phase when it is needed.